# Logic classes symbolic logic

Tags: logic

I have been reading Symbolic Logic by John venn and about the propositions of Aristotle. In symbolic language John Venn refers to subject and predicates in terms of classes. Does anyone know any more detail about what a class actually is?

Comment: "Class" is often used as a generic term for predicables such as properties, categories, concepts, sets, etc. Often, the word "class" is used in contexts where they are primarily focused on the things in the classes or on the practice of dividing things up into classes rather than the nature or implications of the predicables themselves.

Comment: Class is the extension of a predicate i e the collection of objects to which that predicate applies. The collection of red objects wrt the predicate *red*.

Comment: Everything above + "class" is often used when one wishes to be agnostic about the background set theory. Alternatively, you can look for a formal treatment of classes - NBG set theory- but this is not standard, ie not what everyone means when they say class